# My asynchronous function is not running correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Async await is not working. I need to wait for my image to load, move to a state, and then move on. Is not working.

```
export default () => {
  const [imgTmp, setImgTmp] = useState(null);

  const chooseImage = async () => {
    await ImagePicker.showImagePicker('', r => {
      if (r.uri) {
        let img = {uri: r.uri};
        setImgTmp(img);
      }
    });
    alert('...');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{height: 40, backgroundColor: '#DDDD'}}>
        <Image source={imgTmp} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
      </View>
      <Button title="Select Imagem" onPress={chooseImage} />

      {imgTmp !== null ? (
        <DynamicCollage width={400} height={400} images={imgTmp} matrix={[1]} />
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImagePicker.showImagePicker` doesn't return a Promise, so awaiting it won't work as expected.

What you can do is to wrap it with a Promise:

```
  const chooseImage = async () => {
    try {
      const img = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ImagePicker.showImagePicker('', r => {
          if (r.uri) {
            const img = {uri: r.uri};
            resolve(img);
          }
          reject("uri undefined");
        });
      });
      setImgTmp(img);
      alert('...');
    } catch(e) {
     // handle exception
     console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: @Silva, does this answer your question?